# Running Script not showing on EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I just installed all necessary dependencies on a new AWS EC2 Linux 2 server and launch my long_running_script.py. This script essentially performs a few operations then sleeps for a few hours on a never ending loop.

When I launched the script initially, I saw the correct output and all was fine. I disconnected from the instance, and when I reconnected I expected to see the same output as before.

Instead I can't seem to see any script output or see it running after typing in the 'ps aux' command.

Did disconnecting from the instance somehow abort the script? If so, how can I make sure it stays running?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/88092/767065

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Did disconnecting from the instance somehow abort the script? If so, how can I make sure it stays running?

Yes it did. There are many ways to solve this. You can  launch it using [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) or [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). Lunching your program in these "shells" will keep it running after you log out.

There is also [nohup](https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/) and [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) which could also be helpful.

Comment: thanks - I installed tmux. Works great. Just one point though, my script produces a somewhat lengthy output.  I can see it prints everything when watching in real time but then seems to truncate the top 90% once the script executes. Any idea how I can always see the full output from the script? Thanks again

Comment: @Jat90 tmux should have some settings to extend the output. If not you can redirect it to some file.

Comment: thanks. the output is well below the 2000 scroll back default. I extended it 5000 for fun anyways but not difference. I'll raise another post, thanks again